# How to retrieve the RSExecRole name of the SQL server name using the sql query?

Tags: sql

I tried the below, but I failed to get the record alone. Any clue that what I am missing here.

```
SELECT users.name, groups.name
FROM sysmembers membs 
    JOIN sysusers users on membs.memberuid = users.uid 
    JOIN sysusers groups on membs.groupuid = groups.uid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I got it.......

```
SELECT members.name AS UserName, RTRIM(LTRIM(roles.name)) AS RoleName 
FROM sys.database_principals members 
  INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members drm 
    ON members.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id 
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals roles 
    ON drm.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id 
WHERE members.name <> 'dbo'
ORDER BY members.name
```